# TinkerPop Java API language level

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, titan, tinkerpop3

I set Intellij Project Settings -> Modules -> Language level to 1.8.

But when I include tinkerpop 3.0.1-incubating in my pom file, the language level will automatically change to 5.0. Then I change it back to 1.8 manually.

When I try to run my program, there is a compile error:
javac: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

I really want to use some features like switch(String) which is not available in 5.0.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you specify in your Maven pom file that you want to use Java 8? Maven uses Java 5 by default if you don't specify anything.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. I think you'll find everything you need in the linked answers.

Comment: Thanks, guys. It worked.